# Android Espresso, RecyclerViewActions ask for permission

Tags: android, android-testing, android-espresso

I'm trying to test what happens when the user click on an item on a recycler view, and assert that the text displayed in the new activity is ok.

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class MainActivityTest {

    @Rule
    public ActivityTestRule<MainActivity> mainActivityTestRule =
            new ActivityTestRule<>(MainActivity.class);

    @Test
    public void test() {
        onView(withId(R.id.recycler_view)).perform(RecyclerViewActions.actionOnItemAtPosition(24, click()));
        onView(withId(R.id.pokemon_id)).check(matches(withText("# 25")));
    }

}
```

I'm getting this error message:

```
android.support.test.espresso.PerformException: Error performing 'single click - At Coordinates: 269, 933 and precision: 16, 16' on view 'with id: com.melorriaga.pokemon:id/recycler_view'.
at android.support.test.espresso.PerformException$Builder.build(PerformException.java:83)
at android.support.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler.getUserFriendlyError(DefaultFailureHandler.java:80)
at android.support.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler.handle(DefaultFailureHandler.java:56)
at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.runSynchronouslyOnUiThread(ViewInteraction.java:184)
at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.doPerform(ViewInteraction.java:115)
at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.perform(ViewInteraction.java:87)
at com.melorriaga.pokemon.MainActivityTest.test(MainActivityTest.java:67)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
at android.support.test.internal.statement.UiThreadStatement.evaluate(UiThreadStatement.java:55)
at android.support.test.rule.ActivityTestRule$ActivityStatement.evaluate(ActivityTestRule.java:270)
at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
at android.support.test.internal.runner.TestExecutor.execute(TestExecutor.java:59)
at android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:262)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1944)
Caused by: android.support.test.espresso.PerformException: Error performing 'Send down motion event' on view 'unknown'.
at android.support.test.espresso.PerformException$Builder.build(PerformException.java:83)
at android.support.test.espresso.action.MotionEvents.sendDown(MotionEvents.java:104)
at android.support.test.espresso.action.Tap.sendSingleTap(Tap.java:133)
at android.support.test.espresso.action.Tap.access$100(Tap.java:35)
at android.support.test.espresso.action.Tap$1.sendTap(Tap.java:40)
at android.support.test.espresso.action.GeneralClickAction.perform(GeneralClickAction.java:98)
at android.support.test.espresso.contrib.RecyclerViewActions$ActionOnItemAtPositionViewAction.perform(RecyclerViewActions.java:303)
at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$1.run(ViewInteraction.java:144)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)
Caused by: android.support.test.espresso.InjectEventSecurityException: java.lang.SecurityException: Injecting to another application requires INJECT_EVENTS permission
at android.support.test.espresso.base.InputManagerEventInjectionStrategy.innerInjectMotionEvent(InputManagerEventInjectionStrategy.java:162)
at android.support.test.espresso.base.InputManagerEventInjectionStrategy.innerInjectMotionEvent(InputManagerEventInjectionStrategy.java:160)
at android.support.test.espresso.base.InputManagerEventInjectionStrategy.injectMotionEvent(InputManagerEventInjectionStrategy.java:132)
at android.support.test.espresso.base.EventInjector.injectMotionEvent(EventInjector.java:96)
at android.support.test.espresso.base.UiControllerImpl$3.call(UiControllerImpl.java:223)
at android.support.test.espresso.base.UiControllerImpl$3.call(UiControllerImpl.java:220)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Injecting to another application requires INJECT_EVENTS permission
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1546)
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1499)
at android.hardware.input.IInputManager$Stub$Proxy.injectInputEvent(IInputManager.java:417)
at android.hardware.input.InputManager.injectInputEvent(InputManager.java:681)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at android.support.test.espresso.base.InputManagerEventInjectionStrategy.innerInjectMotionEvent(InputManagerEventInjectionStrategy.java:146)
... 11 more
```

Basically: `Injecting to another application requires INJECT_EVENTS permission`

The weird thing is that, if I replace `24` with `0`, `1`, `2` (any item visible without the need to scroll) the test pass.

Any ideas?

https://github.com/matoelorriaga/pokemon-mvp/blob/master/app/src/androidTest/java/com/melorriaga/pokemon/MainActivityTest.java

Comment: Seems that you are tapping on keyboard, which is the another application. That is why you have such a error - since Espresso can't operate outside of app under test. Try to close keyboard or disable it from settings.

Comment: i'm not :( you can check a gif here: `https://github.com/matoelorriaga/pokemon-mvp/`

Comment: Then I have no other idea, ask you question here - https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/android-testing-support-library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found the solution:

```
onView(withId(R.id.recycler_view)).perform(RecyclerViewActions.scrollToPosition(30));
onView(withId(R.id.recycler_view)).perform(RecyclerViewActions.actionOnItemAtPosition(24, click()));
onView(withId(R.id.pokemon_id)).check(matches(withText("# 25")));
```

Basically, first you need to scroll to some position that makes the item to be clicked visible (If I scroll to 24, it is still not visible on screen, so the test fail).

Anyway, I think that `actionOnItemAtPosition` should handle that for us..

Answer (score 0):

RecyclerView works in a way that items which are not visible on a screen are not part of the view hierarchy. Adapter views will be inflated later if you scroll down.

And there are espresso matchers available for that: https://google.github.io/android-testing-support-library/docs/espresso/lists/index.html#recyclerviews

```
public static void tapRecyclerViewItem(int recyclerViewId, int position) {
    onView(withId(recyclerViewId)).perform(scrollToPosition(position));
    onView(withRecyclerView(recyclerViewId).atPosition(position)).perform(click());
}
```

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/espresso/contrib/RecyclerViewActions.html `actionOnItemAtPosition` docs says that it first scroll and then perform the action, also, `withRecyclerView` ViewMatcher does not exist.

Comment: I found an interesting link: https://spin.atomicobject.com/2016/04/15/espresso-testing-recyclerviews/

Comment: I tried with this class https://gist.github.com/baconpat/8405a88d04bd1942eb5e430d33e4faa2 and it doesn't work.